Unable to run windows docker image in windows server 2019
I am trying to use windows docker image as a jenkins agent , this image has to run in a windows 2019 server. But the image has an issue  while running Seeing an  error message.

java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'win:latest'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: hcs::CreateComputeSystem 071368a08fa1ee3f0bb765cf271cd0e8bc2a2c6c3ae8a30dd5e6f633037524e4: The parameter is incorrect.

In my jenkins file I am using this in agent section
But I see this error while running the image.
Please suggest some solution
I tried to run this image , if I manually run this is working in the windows server But when I do it through jenkins it's not working , The issue is reproducible
